# IsMouseOver and DragLeave not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mouseover

I have a grid/panel on my UI that can take a drop action.  The control is a Grid with some dynamically created content in it (a viewbox containing a stack panel of borders if that matters).

When I drag relevant information into the grid I want it to change (regenerate) the internal content and when it drops or leaves it should go back to normal.  I have the 'change it' and 'put it back' methods working just fine, but I'm having trouble determining when to call them.

I have drag enter and drag leave events on the grid.  The enter works great, but the leave is not.  As soon as the mouse gets over the top of the content inside of the grid it fires a drag leave event, so it changes the content (and if that puts it back out of the child content it fires the drag enter again and just flashes).

My first thought was to just determine if the mouse is actually still over the grid and just ditch out without putting the content back.  However this doesn't seem to be working.  Here is my code for drag leave:

```
        private void Grid_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var wizard = DataContext as WizardVM;
        var gd = sender as Grid;

        if (wizard == null || gd == null || gd.IsMouseOver ||
            gd.Children.Cast<FrameworkElement>().Any(x => x.IsMouseOver)) return;

        wizard.Assembly.CollapsePreview();
    }
```

As you can see, I even tried to iterate the children of the grid and see if mouse over is true on any of those and ditch out, and still it just keeps returning false for all of that and collapsing.  I thought IsMouseOver was supposed to tell me if the mouse is over at all even if it's children of the control...

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: IsMouseOver will not be true.  The normal mouse handling is suspended while a D+D operation is in progress.  Hard to see how anybody could propose an alternative from this snippet.

Comment: Oops, sorry it's WPF.  So Hans you are saying there is no way at all to tell if there the mouse is in the bounds of the grid?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well after some more research I found something that seems to be working.  I ended up having to use VisualTreeHelper.HitTest and use the overload that has a callback and gets all hit items even if it's obscured.  Here is my final code:

```
    void Grid_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var wizard = DataContext as WizardVM;
        var gd = sender as Grid;

        if (wizard == null || gd == null) return;
        Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);
        hitResults.Clear();
        VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(gd, null, GridHitTestResultCallback,
            new PointHitTestParameters(pt));

        if (!hitResults.Contains(gd))
        {
            wizard.Assembly.IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }

    HitTestResultBehavior GridHitTestResultCallback(HitTestResult result)
    {
        hitResults.Add(result.VisualHit);
        return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
    }
```

Basically it gets the point in relation to the full window, then calls HitTest with that point and the overall grid I'm trying to work with.  The callback populates a list of visuals that are hit by the hit test.  Last the original method checks if the grid is in the list of hits and if not it collapses it.

As a side note I also changed from .ExpandPreview() and .CollapsePreview() methods to a .IsExpanded property for unrelated reasons... didn't want anyone to be confused by that change...